# If/else function compiler optimization

Tags: c, volatile

I have the following code:

```
if (a > uplimit)
{
   a = a - uplimit;
   indicator = 2;
}
else if (a < lolimit)
{
   a = a - lolimit;
   indicator = 4;
}
```

When I compile and run the code, it seems like the code can never go to indicator = 2 or indicator = 4 given a > uplimit or a < lolimit.

However, if I add something at the beginning of each code section, it works.

```
if (a > uplimit)
{
   c = 1;
   a = a - uplimit;
   indicator = 2;
}
else if (a < lolimit)
{
   c = 2;
   a = a - lolimit;
   indicator = 4;
}
```

It seems like the compiler is trying to optimize the code. I know using volatile might solve this problem. Does anyone know other method that could solve the problem?

By the way, I am using Code Composer Studio.

Comment: You need to clarify what your problem is. We can't read your mind.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? You just want the debugger to step on the optimized line?

Comment: Do you mean? *the code can never go to indicator = 2 or indicator = 4 given `a <= uplimit` and `a >= lolimit`*

Comment: This is just one piece of my project. I find the problem must be here. The code can never go to indicator = 2 or indicator = 4 given a <= uplimit or a >= lolimit

Comment: Your compiler would optimize the code away, if it believes that it does nothing. To tell it that it is wrong you are using the `volatile` keyword. What wrong with using that? (BTW, you are missing the case of a==lolimit)

Comment: if `a` is a **signed integer** type and uplimit is the max value of that type, `a` cannot have a value greater that that max value. If that were the case that would be **undefined behavior**. Compiler has to generate valid code only for the valid paths of execution, i.e. when a < max value. So he can consider that (for a valid program) a is always < max value. So it can say those conditions are always true (for a valid program) and remove the `if`s

Comment: but you don't give us all the information about the code so there are a lot of `if`s in my previous comment.

Comment: Since you are asking for another method to solve this I am assuming you just want to step through the code normally when debugging. They way to do that is to build the code in Debug mode (or turn off Code optimization when debugging).

Comment: To know why/if it is valid to optimise away any of this code, it would be necessary to see the entire function.  "It seems like..." is less than convincing; how have you determined that?  Have you looked at the disassembly or stepped the code in your debugger?  Are you even using compiler optimisation?

Comment: Add a `printf("P1: a = %d, lo = %d, hi = %d\n", a, lolimit, uplimit);` before the condition in the question; add `printf("P2: a = %d, lo = %d, hi = %d, ind=%d\n", a, lolimit, uplimit, indicator);` after the code block.  Show us the test runs which are mishandled.  Note that the 'lolimit' code pushes `a` further away from the low limit; should that `-` be a `+`?  And neither guarantees that `a` is within bounds after the block of code if `a` is far enough out of bounds beforehand (even if the `+` vs `-` issue is fixed).